# Flutter - "Finished with error: The plugin assets_audio_player could not be built due to the issue above."

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, flutter-test

I got this error when i try to run my app. The real question that i wanted to ask, this project works on my macOS, but my windows pc can't run it.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Nexoft\Desktop\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\assets_audio_player-1.4.2\android\build.gradle' line: 25
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':assets_audio_player'.
 Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.
 Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
 Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin assets_audio_player...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Unzipping C:\Users\Nexoft\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.4.1-all\3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx\gradle-5.4.1-all.zip to C:\Users\Nexoft\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.4.1-all\3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx
Finished with error: The plugin assets_audio_player could not be built due to the issue above.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

The things i tried:

- flutter clean
- flutter pub repair
- pub upgrade
- different versions of gradle.build

My pubspec.yaml libs:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  assets_audio_player: 1.4.2
  easy_localization: 1.3.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1
  flutter_icons: ^0.1.4
  sprintf: ^4.0.0
  firebase_admob: 0.9.3+2
  launch_review: ^2.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.2
  numberpicker: ^1.0.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^3.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.8.2
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.3.1
  screen: ^0.0.5
  path_provider: ^1.5.1+1
  fl_chart: ^0.7.0
  flutter_email_sender: ^2.0.3
  audioplayer: 0.5.2
  audio: 0.0.5
  flutter_animation_progress_bar: ^1.0.0
  slide_countdown_clock: ^1.0.3
  youtube_player_flutter: 6.0.3+2
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  bubble: ^1.1.9+1
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.1+1
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.0.4+2
  camera: ^0.5.2+1
  koukicons: ^2.0.2
  flutter_counter: ^1.0.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.7.0
  devicelocale: ^0.2.1
  horizontal_calendar: ^0.0.4
  step_progress_indicator: ^0.2.1+4
  flutter_plugin_tts: ^1.0.2
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  flutter_tts: ^1.1.0
  flutter_youtube: ^2.0.0
  device_info: ^0.4.2+4
```

I am using these pubspec.yaml libraries on my macOS and this file works without errors, but the same file fails on my Windows computer. I tried to remove the assets_audio_player folder and when I remove this folder I get the same error but the only difference is flutter_email_sender lib instead of assets_audio_player.

Comment: Hi Ergun Welcome to SO. please check if you have kotlin plugin installed and configured in you current project.

Comment: Hi Faiizii, 
I checked it from sdk manager- plugins, Kotlin 1.4.20-release is already installed.

Comment: add your audio player lib which you have added in pubspec

Comment: I already added that lib and i have assets_audio_player 1.4.2 folder in my flutter tools, which is in my pubspec.yaml.

Comment: ok I meant that add in the question

Comment: have you checked this lib https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers ? it is more stable & upvoted than yours. Looks like problem with your lib code

Comment: Update your lib will resolve the issue. the latest version is `2.0.13+1` whereas you are using 1.4.2

Comment: I just tried it, I got the error message: "assets_audio_player plugin 'requires your app to be migrated to Android embed v2".

Comment: yes you need to migrate your old project to v2 version

Comment: Thanks Faiizii i will try.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue was because of the Android build in the Flutter project seems to be yet to migrated to AndroidX. You can follow this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/androidx-migration) to migrate the existing app to use AndroidX.